# how do i modify this javascript code to match the value of mine i got

Tags: javascript

i want to change these values to the html value i got so that i can change the value with other javascript code i have.

i want to click the textbox and also activate the focus and add random string.
the string can be later on changed however i need assistance to clicking that textbox and assigning a value to it and also activationg the focus.

```
if (inputs[i].querySelector('input').getAttribute('placeholder') === 'value') {
```

here is the html code i want to assign to javascript

```
<input class="appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2.5 border placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none text-sm rounded-lg border-gray-200 focus:ring-1 focus:border-transparent focus:ring-purple-1" placeholder="Artificial Intelligence in Copywriting" value="">
```

full code i have that i am trying to make it work. it is not working because i am doing something wrong

```
const inputs =  document.querySelectorAll('.text-sm ')

for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].querySelector('input').getAttribute('placeholder') === 'value') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      inputs[i].click()
      inputs[i].innerText = 'explain about jinns in islam short';
    }, 2000 * i);
    inputs[i].click()


  }
   inputs[i].click()
}
```

style code

```
appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2.5 border placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none text-sm rounded-lg border-gray-200 focus:ring-1 focus:border-transparent focus:ring-purple-1
```

```
<input class="appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2.5 border placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none text-sm rounded-lg border-gray-200 focus:ring-1 focus:border-transparent focus:ring-purple-1" placeholder="Artificial Intelligence in Copywriting" value="">
```

this is what i have but it is not working because the format i modifed it in is wrong i guess.

just an update here is what i also found that stores value. this is the area i really need to modify

**`e = input.appearance-none.block.w-full.px-3.py-2.5.border.placeholder-gray-400.focus:outline-none.text-sm.rounded-lg.border-gray-200.focus:ring-1.focus:border-transparent.focus:ring-purple-1 {__reactFiber$xnoy65d6ci: ia, __reactProps$xnoy65d6ci: {…}, _wrapperState: {…}, __reactEvents$xnoy65d6ci: Set(1), …}, n = undefined, t = "ooo0000"`**

were you see the string  ooo0000 needs to be modified with our own custom string

Comment: updated post please check and assist